# django send_email not sending to host domain email addresses

Tags: django, gmail, cpanel

My Django (hosted through a **cPanel Python App**) is not sending out emails to addresses belonging to the same domain as the site.

The same `send_email()` function works fine in sending out messages to any other domain.

I use **Google Workspace** for managing emails, and all MX records are set up via cPanel as normal – and emails otherwise work fine via Gmail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the local SMTP server to send emails? If so, there's a chance that's trying to deliver same-domain emails to local mailboxes rather than gmail.

Comment: Thanks @ben, updating the SMTP servers to Google's default has actually solved it. Much appreciated!

Comment: No worries. Now, I don't know if/how you can do this via cPanel, but it should be possible to configure the mail exchanger to act as a backup, or to default to remote MXs. Like this, you can still use the local SMTP server to send mail but, instead of same-domain messages being delivered locally, they will be forwarded to whatever the lowest numbered MX in your DNS entries is. Presumably, that would be one of Google's in your case.